# In this sentence, is the "in" optional in colloquial US English?

Tags: usage

In colloquial usage, is the "in" optional in a sentence like this:

Did she lose her sense of humor (in) the same place she lost her sense of fashion?

Comment: I think what you are trying to say is "Did she lose her sense of humor the same *way* she lost her sense of fashion?" As you wrote it, it would be natural to use *in*, though it implies a location (place) which may not be what you mean.

Comment: I did imply an imaginary location here. Maybe my example wasn't good enough. I've often heard a sentence like this without the "in," which is why I asked.

Comment: I wouldn't say optional, but in informal speech some prepositions get shortened or skipped when the meaning in context is understood. In your example, in/at or no preposition does not change the meaning.